# why do I have this error message from React

Tags: reactjs

I have this error when I create a test.js file and have the following code.

```js
var models = require('./server.js').modles;

models.Profile.create({name: 'nick'}, (err, profile) => {
    console.log ("data?" , err, profile);
});
```

the error message was:

> models.Profile.create({name: 'nick'}, (err, profile) => { TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'Profile' of undefined

Any one can help with this?

Comment: Is your model object really named `modles`?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it would appear that your 'models' object doesn't exist as an object, which you are accessing it as. So this line

```
var models = require('./server.js').modles;
```

...doesn't bring anything back. So your next line:

```
models.Profile....
```

So 'models' won't have anything in it. So when you access 'Profile' of 'models', it says, 'Cannot read property 'Profile' of undefined'. In this case, models is undefined.

One way to fix it is to change your load:

```
var models = require('./server.js').modles || {};
```

Then it is an empty object and won't give the error you are getting. Another way is to fix the object you're loading and as one commentator mentioned, are you sure it's 'modles' (spelling) that you're trying to load? Could the spelling mistake be the issue?

Comment: oh my god! Thank you so much. How silly me. It was the spelling mistake.